# Django do not allow another like if user already liked a post

Tags: python, html, django

I want to allow an user to be able to like an post only once. Here is my code so far:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

In views.py:

```
def LikePostView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.likes = post.likes+1
    post.save()
    return render(request, 'blog/like_done.html')
```

Code to like a post on frontend:

```
<p class="content">{{ post.likes }} likes</p>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   <a href='{% url "like_post" post.id %}'><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:36px"></i></a>
{% else %}
   <a onclick="alert('In order to like a post, you must be logged in!')" href='{% url "blog-home" %}'><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:36px"></i></a>
{% endif %}
```

And like_done.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2 class="alert alert-success">Post Liked Successfuly!</h2>
    <br>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Go Back Home?</a>
    <br>
{% endblock content %}
```

So with all this, how would I make the user be allowed to only like a post once. I am only beginner, so please explain a little.

Comment: I think your thinking about how it should be stored in the database is not correct. You just count likes on a post, however a real like means a USER can like many POSTs (and a POST can be liked by many USERs) so you need a table (many-to-many) which keep tracks of the ```user.id``` as well as the ```post.id```  - which is also the composite key making it unique.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, You want a user to be able to like a post once, and when the user clicks on the like button the second time it should 'unlike' right?

If so, this is what you should do:

In you Post model, the like should be like this `likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_likes')`, a `ManyToManyField`.

Then in your views:

```
def LikePostView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.user in post.likes.all():
       post.likes.remove(request.user)
    else:
       post.likes.add(request.user)
    return render(request, 'blog/like_done.html')
```

This way if the user clicks the like button he will be added to the `likes Field` and if he clicks it again he will be removed seems he is already there. So the user won't be able to like a post more than once.